cannot import name 'Vapi' from 'vapi_python'
I have installed library vapi_python
as I am getting this after checking if is installed:
pip show vapi_python
Name: vapi-python
Version: 0.1.0
Summary: This package lets you start Vapi calls directly from Python.
Home-page: https://github.com/jordan.cde/vapi_python
Author: Vapi AI
Author-email: team@vapi.ai
License: MIT license
Location: c:\users\asdf\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: Click
Required-by: 

Then I simply wrote this code
from vapi_python import Vapi
vapi = Vapi(api_key='your-public-key')

assistant = {
  'firstMessage': 'Hey, how are you?',
  'context': 'You are an employee at a drive thru...',
  'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
  'voice': 'jennifer-playht',
  "recordingEnabled": True,
  "interruptionsEnabled": False
}

vapi.start(assistant=assistant)

I replaced my api key in original code but I am getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects\Final\vapi\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from vapi_python import Vapi
ImportError: cannot import name 'Vapi' from 'vapi_python' (C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vapi_python\__init__.py)

I have tried on different devices to make sure this is not an issue in my device but it is same on all the other devices

Can you move your vapi folder containing your app.py file to C drive? And try again. What do you get?

Yeah I tried that but still I am getting that same error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\TestFolder\app.py", line 1, in 
from vapi_python import Vapi
ImportError: cannot import name 'Vapi' from 'vapi_python' (C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vapi_python_init_.py)
